# How to create index using CreateMappingDescriptor for Elastic Search using NEST client?

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

I have successfully created a descriptor for my Index. Have already created the index. The response generated is a valid response. 
I am not sure how to use descriptor thereafter.

```
var defaultIndex = "mynestclient";
var node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
 var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node
            ).DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);
        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
        var clientcreated= client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex);
        Console.WriteLine("Index Created");

var descriptor = new CreateIndexDescriptor(defaultIndex)
                    .Settings(s => s
                    .Analysis(a => a
                        .TokenFilters(t => t
                            .NGram("my_filter", ng => ng.MaxGram(32).MinGram(1)))
                        .Analyzers(an => an
                            .Custom("my_analyzer", ca => ca
                                .Tokenizer("standard")
                                .Filters("my_filter", "lowercase")
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
                .Mappings(ms => ms
                    .Map<Investor>(m => m
                        .Properties(props => props
                            .Text(t => t
                                .Name(p => p.Name)
                                .Analyzer("my_analyzer")
                            )
                            .Text(t => t
                                .Name(p => p.SomeOtherField)
                                .Analyzer("my_analyzer"))
                            .Boolean(b => b
                                .Name(p => p.IsActive))));
```

I have been through the documentation. Not much around using Descriptors.
Also, if anybody could point me to a documentation around NEST that specifies difference between PutMappingDescriptors and CreateIndexDescriptors, or Likewise, that would be helpful. 
Any inputs greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Descriptors are types for fluently building up a request to an Elasticsearch endpoint with NEST. A Descriptor is then passed to the corresponding method on the client. For example,

```
var descriptor = new CreateIndexDescriptor(defaultIndex)
                    .Settings(s => s
                    .Analysis(a => a
                        .TokenFilters(t => t
                            .NGram("my_filter", ng => ng.MaxGram(32).MinGram(1)))
                        .Analyzers(an => an
                            .Custom("my_analyzer", ca => ca
                                .Tokenizer("standard")
                                .Filters("my_filter", "lowercase")
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
                .Mappings(ms => ms
                    .Map<Investor>(m => m
                        .Properties(props => props
                            .Text(t => t
                                .Name(p => p.Name)
                                .Analyzer("my_analyzer")
                            )
                            .Text(t => t
                                .Name(p => p.SomeOtherField)
                                .Analyzer("my_analyzer"))
                            .Boolean(b => b
                                .Name(p => p.IsActive))));

var createIndexResponse = client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex, c => descriptor);
```

The second parameter in the `CreateIndex()` method is a `Func<CreateIndexDescriptor, ICreateIndexRequest>` so the `c` parameter is a `CreateIndexDescriptor` passed to the delegate, so you can simply fluently build up the parameters from this instead

```
var createIndexResponse = client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex, c => c
      .Settings(s => s
        .Analysis(a => a
            .TokenFilters(t => t
                .NGram("my_filter", ng => ng.MaxGram(32).MinGram(1)))
            .Analyzers(an => an
                .Custom("my_analyzer", ca => ca
                    .Tokenizer("standard")
                    .Filters("my_filter", "lowercase")
                )
            )
        )
    )
    .Mappings(ms => ms
        .Map<Investor>(m => m
            .Properties(props => props
                .Text(t => t
                    .Name(p => p.Name)
                    .Analyzer("my_analyzer")
                )
                .Text(t => t
                    .Name(p => p.SomeOtherField)
                    .Analyzer("my_analyzer"))
                .Boolean(b => b
                    .Name(p => p.IsActive))))
    )
);
```

The API design with Descriptors is that instead of needing to instantiate new instances of Descriptors yourself, methods take a `Func<TRequestDescriptor, TRequestInterface>` where the Descriptor is created for you, and you then just need to call the methods that you need to, to set the properties that you want in the request, similar to what you have done with `.Settings()`, `.Mappings()`, etc. This is referred to as a the Fluent Lambda syntax.

NEST also provides Request types for all APIs too (referred to as the Object Initializer syntax), if Func delegates and lambda expressions are not your thing. Request types also implement the relevant `TRequestInterface` in each case, and each method on the NEST client is overloaded to take a `TRequestInterface`. The Object Initializer equivalent of the example above is

```
var createIndexRequest = new CreateIndexRequest(defaultIndex)
{
    Settings = new IndexSettings
    {
        Analysis = new Analysis
        {
            TokenFilters = new TokenFilters
            {
                { "my_filter", new NGramTokenFilter
                    {
                        MaxGram = 32,
                        MinGram = 1
                    } 
                }
            },
            Analyzers = new Analyzers
            {
                { "my_analyzer", new CustomAnalyzer
                    {
                        Tokenizer = "standard",
                        Filter = new[] {"my_filter", "lowercase" }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    Mappings = new Mappings
    {
        { typeof(Investor), new TypeMapping
            {
                Properties = new Properties<Investor>
                {
                    { i => i.Name, new TextProperty
                        {
                            Analyzer = "my_analyzer"
                        }
                    },
                    { i => i.SomeOtherField, new TextProperty
                        {
                            Analyzer = "my_analyzer"
                        }
                    },
                    { i => i.IsActive, new BooleanProperty() }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

var createIndexResponse  = client.CreateIndex(createIndexRequest);
```

Use the Fluent Lambda syntax, the Object Initializer syntax, or both, it's up to you :)

> Also, if anybody could point me to a documentation around NEST that specifies difference between PutMappingDescriptors and CreateIndexDescriptors, or Likewise, that would be helpful.

`PutMappingDescriptor` puts a mapping into an existing index whereas `CreateIndexDescriptor` creates an index where you can optionally create the mapping at the same time. The topic is discussed in the [introduction to the mapping section](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/mapping.html) in the documentation.